# Rails Action Cable and Turbolinks: avoid multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, actioncable, turbolinks-5

I have a code in my application.html.haml that decides whether to subscribe the user to a given channel or not, depending on some user attribute.

The thing is that, given I have this piece of code in the body, when I click a link to be redirected to another page, it subscribes the user again instead of keeping the old connection, so I have the `receive()` method being executed multiple times.

This is my code in `application.html.haml`:

```
%html
  %head
    -# other stuff
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    -# other stuff

    - if current_user.is_admin?
      :coffee
        MyApp.AdminNotifications.init()
```

**assets/javascripts/notifications/admin_notifications.js.coffee**

```
window.MyApp.AdminNotifications = class AdminNotifications
  @init: ->
    App.cable.subscriptions.create "ProductsChannel",
      received: (data) ->
        console.log 'Data Received' # This is being executed multiple times
```

The first time the page is loaded, when I broadcast a message to that channel, the console is logging "Data Received" just once.
I click a link to be redirected to another page, I broadcast a new message to that channel, and now the console is logging "Data Received" twice. And so far so on...

In fact, when I run on the chrome's console:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.subscriptions
```

It returns multiple subscriptions to the same channel (once for every time I clicked on a link and got redirected to a different page).

Note: There is more action cable setup that I am not adding to this post because it's working fine.

How can I avoid that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only want a single instance of `MyApp.AdminNotifications`, so you may only need to add a class attribute to flag that the class has been initialized:

```
window.MyApp.AdminNotifications = class AdminNotifications
  @init: ->
    unless @initialized
      App.cable.subscriptions.create "ProductsChannel",
        received: (data) ->
          console.log 'Data Received'
      @initialized = true
```

In the future you may want to wrap the Action Cable API to manage your own subscriptions.

---

As a general rule when working with Turbolinks, it is preferable to include as much stuff as possible in your application.js file rather than in inline scripts (see: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23012#issue-125970208). I'm guessing you used an inline script so you could conditionally run it (`if current_user.is_admin?`). A popular approach is to use meta tags to convey this data, so in your head:

```
<meta name="current-user-is-admin" content="true">
```

Then you could have:

```
window.MyApp.User = class User
  constructor: ->
    @isAdmin = @getMeta('current-user-is-admin') == 'true'

  getMeta: (name) ->
    meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=#{name}]")
    meta.getAttribute('content') if meta
```

And finally, to remove the `AdminNotifications` init code from the layout include this somewhere in your application.js:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ->
  window.MyApp.currentUser = new window.MyApp.User
  window.MyApp.AdminNotifications.init() if window.MyApp.currentUser.isAdmin
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! If you have found this answer to solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted". Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

How about writing in head instead of body?
Perhaps the event has been registered multiple times by turbolinks.

```
%html
  %head
    -# other stuff
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'

    - if current_user.is_admin?
      :coffee
        MyApp.AdminNotifications.init()

  %body
    -# other stuff
```